# Zend Framework on Mac: -bash: ./zf.sh: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: Operation not permitted

Tags: php, macos, bash, zend-framework, sh

I am trying to set up Zend Framework on my Mac (Max OS X 10.7.3). While I had done it in the past, I am running into a problem with the Zend Tool that I had never experienced before. In particular, when I try to run the Zend Tool (zf.sh), I always get this error:

```
-bash: ./zf.sh: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: Operation not permitted
```

The problem doesn't appear to be with the Shell itself, since the binary is right where it should be. I tried to modify the script to use Bash, but the result is the same. I am getting this error by running `./zf.sh` from the same directory where the script is located (which is my Downloads folder, at the moment). If I use `sh zf.sh` or `bash zf.sh`, however, everything works fine. I have tried all possible approaches that I found to be vaguely related to this issue, to include:

- disable quarantine
- verified that line endings don't contain Cr
- chmod +x the file

None of that made a difference and I am not sure of what could be causing this problem.

Comment: Can you try doing it with sudo?

Comment: Actually, yes, I tried and still didn't work.

Comment: Possibly some funky chars at the end of the `#!` line, like end-of-line marker not the one of your platform.

Comment: I searched and found [this](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.sys.mac.system/2012-02/msg00108.html), which may related. (same error)

Comment: Re-download the zf.sh file using: `curl -O http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/branches/release-1.11/bin/`

Comment: @Mat you were probably correct. I had tried to sanitize the file using BBEdit, but something must have been off. I tried to create a new .sh file, copying and pasting the content of the original zf.sh script, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to have been caused by characters (end-of-line, most likely) not supported by my platform. Interestingly, opening the file in BBEdit, sanitizing the text and then saving it with the correct line-ending characters didn't work. However, copying and pasting the file's content into a new file in BBEdit and then saving it did the trick.

Comment: The problem seems to have been caused by The Unarchiver utility. After extracting the archive using the command line (`tar -zxvf ZendFramework-1.11.11.tar.gz`), everything worked fine.